# Mimic pivot table using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, pivot-table, xslt-1.0, muenchian-grouping

I would like a pivot table that will show the following XML.

```
<Records reportTime24h="18:02" reportTime="06:02:56PM" reportDate="2018-11-24" reportTitle="Pivot table">
<Record>
<Year>2017</Year>
<Month>11</Month>
<Sex>F</Sex>
<TestID>1001</TestID>
<TestName>TRIGLYCERIDEN(501)</TestName>
<Total>91</Total>
</Record>
<Record>
<Year>2017</Year>
<Month>11</Month>
<Sex>F</Sex>
<TestID>1003</TestID>
<TestName>UREUM(501)</TestName>
<Total>62</Total>
</Record>
<Record>
<Year>2017</Year>
<Month>11</Month>
<Sex>M</Sex>
<TestID>1003</TestID>
<TestName>UREUM(501)</TestName>
<Total>1642</Total>
</Record>
<Record>
<Year>2017</Year>
<Month>11</Month>
<Sex>F</Sex>
<TestID>1004</TestID>
<TestName>NATRIUM(501)</TestName>
<Total>72</Total>
</Record>
<Record>
<Year>2017</Year>
<Month>11</Month>
<Sex>M</Sex>
<TestID>1004</TestID>
<TestName>NATRIUM(501)</TestName>
<Total>1929</Total>
</Record>
<Record>
<Year>2017</Year>
<Month>11</Month>
<Sex>F</Sex>
<TestID>1005</TestID>
<TestName>KALIUM(501)</TestName>
<Total>72</Total>
</Record>
<Record>
<Year>2017</Year>
<Month>11</Month>
<Sex>M</Sex>
<TestID>1005</TestID>
<TestName>KALIUM(501)</TestName>
<Total>1929</Total>
</Record>
</Records>
```

Here is what the table should look like.

[image: Pivot table in XSLT]

The cross between rows and columns should be the Total xml node that corresponds to the data intersected.

Is this possible?

PD: I have tried to do this using  muenchian grouping. However, I was not able to iterate of the data across colums effectively. For example, the logic was not able to handle nodes that only had data for one of the genders. I tried to check for data in the node to display a zero (0) but failed.

**EDIT**

To follow the commenters recommendation.

Here is the XSL file that I worked on. It accomplishes the desired result but it fails when a Test only has data for one gender. It will place the data on the first column, regardless of wheter the datum belongs to the columns (gender).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="key-tests" match="Record" use="TestID" />
<xsl:key name="key-sex" match="Record" use="Sex" />

<xsl:key name="key-tests-sex" match="Record" use="concat(TestID,'::',Sex)" />

<xsl:template match="/Records">

<html>

    <head>

        <style>

            body        { font-family: monospace;                                       }
            table       { border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 8pt;                    }
            table thead { background-color: gainsboro; font-weight: bold;               }
            td,th       { border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 3px; min-width: 26px;   }
            tbody td    { text-align: right;                                    }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <table>

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sex</th>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Record[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key-sex',Sex)[1])]" mode="key-sex"/>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="Record[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key-tests',TestID)[1])]" mode="key-tests"/>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('key-sex','F')/Total)"/></th>
                    <th><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('key-sex','M')/Total)"/></th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>       

    </body>

</html>

</xsl:template>
<!--Row Data (totals)-->
<xsl:template match="Record" mode="key-tests-sex">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="Total"/></td>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Doctors (HEADER ROW) -->
<xsl:template match="Record" mode="key-sex">
    <th><xsl:value-of select="Sex"/></th>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Tests (ROWS) -->
<xsl:template match="Record" mode="key-tests">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="TestName"/></td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('key-tests',TestID)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key-tests-sex',concat(TestID,'::',Sex))[1])]" mode="key-tests-sex"/>
    </tr>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the end result image. I only included the portion visible in the view port. It is about 3 pages long. But should be enough to get the idea of what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

**What's wrong with the picture**

The count shown for Female (7) is actually the count for Male.

[image]

Comment: The XML file's data and the table's data do not match. In this state it's impossible to answer your question; even aside the fact that you, by now, have **not shown** any own effort to solve this.

Comment: Hello @zx485. Thansk for replying. The table image I included is just used to illustrate the end result I wish to accoplish. It is not supposed to match the XML data I included. Also, the XML i copied in the question is just a fraction of the actual XML file I am using.

Finally, please look at the the edited question in which you will find:
- The XSL file I used, which almost accomplishes the desired goal.
- I included an image of the resulting HTML file after applying the XSL posted

Apologies for keeping information since this app deals with patient data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the template matching `Record` for mode `key-tests` to

```
<!-- Tests (ROWS) -->
<xsl:template match="Record" mode="key-tests">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="TestName"/></td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('key-tests',TestID)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key-tests-sex',concat(TestID,'::','F'))[1])]/Total"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('key-tests',TestID)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key-tests-sex',concat(TestID,'::','M'))[1])]/Total"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

That at least should fix the problem with the wrong relation of the number and the gender.

As in your real data the different values of the `Sex` element are not restricted to `F` and `M` you will need some way to process the unique values each time to create a `td` cell and inside then map to the relevant `Record` data so the template will become

```
<!-- Tests (ROWS) -->
<xsl:template match="Record" mode="key-tests">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="TestName"/></td>
        <xsl:variable name="testId" select="TestID"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$unique-genders">
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="key('key-tests', $testId)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key-tests-sex',concat(TestID, '::', current()))[1])]/Total"/>  
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

with declarations

```
<xsl:key name="key-sex" match="Sex" use="." />

<xsl:variable name="unique-genders" select="//Sex[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key-sex', .)[1])]"/>
```

as done in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBue/2

Comment: Thanks for replying Martin.  That worked, however, I need a way for the template to automatically accommodate new entries for Sex (e.g. Female - Pregnant). So the key passed to Sex cannot be fixed. Is this possible?

Comment: See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBue/2, I think you want respectively need to process the unique gender values each time to create a `td` and then inside map to the relevant `Record` group if it exists. If the code in the link helps I will morph that into an answer later.

Comment: Martin, yes, that looks like exactly what I need. You are a life saver. I will try it as soon as I can. Thanks for helping.